# Convert nested POJO or JSON to Map<String, String>

Tags: java, jackson

In order to create a **multipart/form-data** request, I need to transform either a **nested POJO** or the **nested JSON** that results from Jackson serialization to a **Map<String, String>** with the following format.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("transaction_id", request.getTransactionId());
map.put("person[dob]", request.getPerson().getDob());
map.put("person[first_name]", request.getPerson().getFirstName());
map.put("person[last_name]", request.getPerson().getLastName());
```

Here are the definitions of the relevant classes.

```
@Getter
public class Request {
  @JsonProperty("transaction_id")
  private String transactionId;
  
  private Person person;
}

@Getter
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty("dob")
    private String dob;

    @JsonProperty(value = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty(value = "last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Is there someway to do the map population automatically from a given `Request` POJO or serialized JSON, e.g. using Jackson that I already use for JSON serialization?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your `Person` object into a `Map` with the [`ObjectMapper#convertValue`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue-java.lang.Object-com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference-) that converts an object to a `map` where the fields' names are keys and values are the fields' values, then add to the obtained map the `transaction_id` key and its value:

```
//map will contain keys = {dob, first_name, last_name} 
//up to you modify the keys' names as you like
Map<String, String> map = mapper.convertValue(request.getPerson(),
                             new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
map.put("transaction_id", request.getTransactionId());
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do it like you want:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("transaction_id", request.getTransactionId());
map.put("person[dob]", request.getPerson().getDob());
map.put("person[first_name]", request.getPerson().getFirstName());
map.put("person[last_name]", request.getPerson().getLastName());
```

You could use `convertValue` method

```
Map<String, Object> map = mapper.convertValue(request,
                             new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});
```

but the resulting map would be something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("transactionId", request.getTransactionId());
map.put("person", new HashMap<String, Object>());
```

For reading that map:

```
String transactionId = map.get("transactionId").toString();
String firstName = ((Map)map.get("person")).get("firstName").toString();
//The same for the rest of the properties
```